# Symbol lookup error while using Tesseract : undefined symbol: _ZN10SIMDDetect14avx_available_E

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, tesseract

I am trying to install Tesseract 4.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 using the workaround mentioned in this link - https://orionfoysal.github.io/Installing-Tesseract4.0/

But I keep getting

> tesseract: symbol lookup error: tesseract: undefined symbol: _ZN10SIMDDetect14avx_available_E

The solution of installing

```
sudo apt install libtesseract-dev libleptonica-dev liblept5
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr -y
```

doesn't work, since I need Tesseract 4.0 and for Ubuntu 16.04 it installs version 3.x

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is no other version of tesseract installed e.g. before installing tesseract (from source or with apt) you must remove previous version.
You can not have multiple version of tesseract installed (unless you know how to handle it ;-) )